# Some property about irrational numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Given some base $b$ integer and an irrational number $x > 1$ is it always possible to find $m \geq 0$ such that $\frac{1}{x}=0.b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 \cdots b_m \cdots$ represented in $b$ base and from the first digit after the point till the digit $m$ can be bigger than the digits from $j$ till $m+j$ for some $j\geq 1$ ?

Examples :

1) $b=2$ and $x=\pi$ => $\frac{1}{\pi}= 0.0101000101111100110000011011011101\cdots$ now we can take $m=1$ which means take the first two digits after the point which are $01$ now sure that this is bigger than the digits in place $j=4$ which are $00$, (note that we can find many cases with other $m$ and $j$, but at least one is sufficient).

2) $b=3$ and $x=e^4$ => $\frac{1}{e^4}= 0.000111100111200101202220200212021000001110011\cdots$ 
now we can take $m=3$ which means take the first four digits after the point which are $0001$ now sure that this is bigger than the digits in place $j=33$ which are $0000$.

any proof of any kind or a ref to some paper concern this problem or something related is most appreciated (also i don't know what tags to attach to this question).

Comment: Have you tried to construct a counterexample? It seems not very difficult to do if you know just a little bit about the decimal representations of irrational numbers. Even in binary an example is not very hard to find if you take (for example) $m=2.$

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're saying. You're saying there exists an $m$ such that there exists a $j$ such that the digit sequence from $1$ to $m$ is less than the digit sequence from $m$ to $m+j$?

Comment: @Stella Biderman not less but bigger, and from $j$ to $j+m$ not from $m$ to $j+m$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Let $\frac 1x=0.01899889889\ldots $ where all the trailing digits are $8$s and $9$s.   As long as there is no repeat the number will be irrational.  All the downstream strings will consist of only $8$s and $9$s while the leading one starts with $01$

Comment: What about $m=3, j=1$? $18>9$

Comment: @StellaBiderman:  they are supposed to have the same number of digits.  $j$ is the starting point, but they each have $m+1$ digits.